# Signature for Doctor of Information Technology prefix and suffix

Tags: writing-style, formatting, email

How can I sign my name with the degree of "[Doctor of Information Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Information_Technology)"?

Is this all correct?

**Dr. Full Name**

**Full Name D.I.T**

**Dr Full Name
(Doctor of Information Technology)**

**Dr. Last Name**

Can I use these kind of signatures in my emails and/or letters? Is there a standard way of doing this?

Note: This question was also asked [on English Language & usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168282/signature-for-doctor-of-information-technology-prefix-and-suffix)

Answer (score 2):

According to both the [University of Calgary Style Guide](http://www.ucalgary.ca/news/styleguide) and the [NYU Langone Office of Communications and Marketing](http://communications.med.nyu.edu/advertising-branding/editorial-style-guide/academic-degrees-licenses-credentials) as two examples, your signature would be

- John M. Doe, DIT

A "Doctor of Information Technology" degree is offered by a very limited number of Universities. I could not find any style guides referring to DIT directly, but given the choices as the OP lists, the two style guides to which I refer state that one should not use periods within the acronym, so it would not be number 2, but would be John M. Doe, DIT.

They go on to state that one should not use the honorific Dr. at the same time as listing the degrees. So Dr. John M. Doe, DIT would not be recommended.

Comment: I don't see "DIT" mentioned anywhere in the two examples given by you. Would you please explain how did you come up with "DIT"?